# PHP HTML select option not working

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a dropdown with 3 choices. Blank, Option A, and Option B. The code should be selecting the correct one, but it's making the wrong one selected.

**Updated code with new parenthesis syntax**

```
    <select name="memType">
        <option value="" selected="<?php if ( ($status !== 'Option A') && ($status !== 'Option B') ){echo 'selected';}?>">None</option>
        <option value="Option A" selected="<?php if (($status) == ('Option A')){echo 'selected';}?>">Option A</option>
        <option value="Option B" selected="<?php if (($status) == ('Option B')){echo 'selected';}?>">Option B</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: There's no more selected='selected' needed in HTML5. Just write selected

Comment: `($status)!== (('Option A')||('Option B'))` - that doesn’t do what you think it does; you need to check both separately and join them with an or. And what’s with all the superfluous brackets?

Comment: Updated code @CBroe

Comment: Why are you checking if the status is not A and not B for the first option anyway? If another ten options get added at some point - are you going to add ten more conditions to that if statement …? Just check if it equals the empty string, which _is_ the value of that option.

Answer (score 0):

@Elbarto is correct, all I needed to do was echo "checked" and not "checked='checked'"

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will work for you :

```
<select name="memType">
    <option value="" selected="<?php if ( ($status != 'Option A') && ($status != 'Option B') ){echo 'selected';}?>">None</option>
     <option value="Option A" selected="<?php if ($status == 'Option A'){echo 'selected';}?>">Option A</option>
    <option value="Option B" selected="<?php if ($status == 'Option B'){echo 'selected';}?>">Option B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Same Issue for me...

```
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Class</label>
      <select name="sclass">

          <option value=""  disabled>Select Class</option>

        <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0){

                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){

                    if($row2['Class_ID'] == $My_Sid ){
                        echo "<option  value='".$row2['Class_ID']." Selected'>".$row2['Class_Name']."</option>";
                    }else{                   
                        echo "<option value='".$row2['Class_ID']."'>".$row2['Class_Name']."</option>";
                    }

                }
            }
        ?>

      </select>
  </div>
```